# German vs. German2 in ElasticSearch's snowball filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with an existing project that uses ElasticSearch's snowball filter.

That filter specifies a language -- in this case, `German2`.

What are the differences between `German` and `German2`? When would you use each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html

According to the links for German and German2 is that German2 allows for various representations of certain characters in the language that occasionally appear in texts.

German: http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/german/stemmer.html

German2: http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/german2/stemmer.html